# How can I get Angry Birds on my Mac?

Tags: imac, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, games

I tried using iTunes, but it only seems to have downloads for iPhone and iPad only. How can I get a version I can play on my iMac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App Store found in iTunes is only for iPhone/iPod/iPad apps. Mac apps can be found on the [Mac App Store](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/). Angry Birds is available for Mac for [$5](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id403961173?mt=12).
You can also play for free online at http://chrome.angrybirds.com/.

Note that iPhone and iPad apps are not linked to desktop Mac apps, so when you buy an app for an iPhone or iPad, it does not come with a Mac version and there is no guarantee that a Mac version is even available.
Sometimes apps are available on both the iOS (iPhone/iPad) App Store and the separate Mac App Store, as is the case for Angry Birds.

Comment: I presume there is no free version available, then?

Comment: @Paul No, I'm afraid there is no free Mac app. You can play the online version for free, but it is limited compared to the apps. This situation isn't specific to Angry Birds; it's true for almost all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not supported anymore.

https://support.rovio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042909613-I-can-t-find-Angry-Birds-Classic-in-my-app-store-anymore-what-s-up-with-that-